# Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Then how you show $A^\perp$ is closed in $X^*$ under the strong topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $A\subseteq X$. Then how you show $A^\perp=\{x^*\in X^*:\langle a,x^*\rangle=0 \textrm{ for all }a\in A\}$ is closed in $X^*$ under the strong topology?

Comment: In what sense the strong topology is?

Comment: $\sigma(X^{\ast},X) \subset b(X^{\ast},X)$, so every weak$^{\ast}$-closed set is strongly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_a:X^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f_a(x)=\langle x,a\rangle$, $f$ is continuous for the strong topology, so $f_a^{-1}(0)$ is closed.

$A^\perp=\cap_{a\in A}f_a^{-1}(0)$, so it is the intersection of closed subsets, hence it is closed.

Comment: I am sorry why $f$ is continuous for the strong topology?

Comment: Because $\|f_a\|\leq \|x\|\|a\|$ where $\|x\|=sup_{\|y\|=1}\|x(y)\|$.